# I install Ubuntu 14.04 mouse, keyboard and LAN are working only in low latency mode

Tags: 14.04, lts

If I select generic the mouse, keyboard, lan etc are not working. Do you have any idea about this one?

or Can I set low latency as the default or first mode?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Low latency is actually a good thing. It's a measurement of response time and the lower the value the faster it is.